# z3py: equivalent to (get-objectives)

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

In Z3 I can call `(get-objectives)` to have a dump of the resulting weights.
(e.g. [here](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/xYVZ))

It prints something like this:

```
(objectives
 (aaa 1)
 (bbb 0)
)
```

In z3py however `Optimize.objectives()` prints a dump of the calculation for the objectives, not however the calculated weights, as seen here:

```
[If(a == 3, 0, 1), If(b == 3, 0, 1)]
```

Is there a way how I can get the calculated weights? or the weight of a specific objective as in the standard z3?

Here is my example code:

```
from z3 import *
a, b = Ints('a b')
s = Optimize()
s.add(3 <= a, a <= 10)
s.add(3 <= b, b <= 10)
s.add(a >= 2*b)
s.add_soft(a == 3, weight=1, id="aaa")
s.add_soft(b == 3, weight=1, id="bbb")
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
print(s.objectives())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the model to evaluate the objectives:

```
m = s.model()
print [m.evaluate(o) for o in s.objectives()]
```

This yields:

```
sat
[1, 0]
```

Comment: Looks good. Is there a way to get the `id` for each evaluated objective?

Comment: I'm not sure. You might want to ask at their github site for clarification.